# Flash player compatibility between Windows and Mac OSX and other OSes?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, macos, actionscript, compatibility

I'm developing a flash application by using actionscript, Flex SDK and text editor.
I want make my flash application support InternetExplorer, FireFox and Chrome on Windows.
But I'm developing it on Mac OSX.

How compatible is flash player of Mac OSX with flash player of Windows?

Do I have to test the application not only on Mac OSX but also on Windows?

How about compatibility with flash player of other OSes, for example, Android, Linux, Wii?

Comment: Most things should be consistent cross OS including Android, linux, Windows and Mac, given the same version of the Flash Player.  I thought Wii had a really old version, (Flash Player 8, I think); so that means no AS3 support there.  And a UI you build for a desktop most likely won't work on a tablet / smartphone screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing you should note about Flash is that it does not run in the browser per se. It runs on a virtual machine deployed with the flash runtime (in the browsers it's the flash plugin).

You are so to say independent of the browsers rendering engine, but the browser may restrict your rights on the machine. In Chrome for example you can't access the filesystem without changing the security settings of the plugin.

Flash runs on all of those platforms, and so does flex. The Wii I am not sure about, but you should be able to run the same code on Linux, Windows and OSX without modification.

The android flash runtime has quite poor performance, so when developing for the phone you should think twice before you go nuts with aniations and such.

The biggest visual issue you will run into is system fonts. The default fonts are different on the systems and therefore your application can vary in appearence

Comment: Very good answer and should be accepted.  To add to this, in my 10 years of doing Flash, I've only seen a handful of problems pertaining to different browsers/OS', most of which are already fixed, or is very well known in the community (ie. the OSX scrolling bug when using the mouse scroller, which is a limitation of the OS' API).  The whole point of Flash is compile once, run everywhere (kind of like java).

Comment: I've had some quite severe visual font issues, but that's mostly because much of the gui I wrote was handwritten and not built using the built-in flex components.